# How to show original price if there's no discount and show discount price only if there's Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, dom-events

I have an array of objects like this:

```
orders : [
{
          id: 1,
          image: require("./assets/imgs/product1.png"),
          originalPrice: 40,
          discountPrice: "",
          buyBtn: require("./assets/icons/buy.svg"),
          likeBtn: require("./assets/icons/like.svg"),
          productName: "Marianna Collection",
          productRating: "★★☆☆☆",
          class: "new"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          
          image: require("./assets/imgs/product2.png"),
          originalPrice: 60,
          discountPrice: 30,
          buyBtn: require("./assets/icons/buy.svg"),
          likeBtn: require("./assets/icons/like.svg"),
          productName: "Marianna Collection",
          productRating: "★★☆☆☆",
          class: "new"
        },
]
```

Now what I want to do is only display one price in my cart,so I want to say:

```
    if discountPrice ! = '' show discountPrice else show originalPrice
```

Here's what I have tried:

```
<td class="tg-lqy6"   :class="order.discountPrice != '' ? 'exist' : ''" id="originalPrice">{{ order.originalPrice }} sr</td>
<td class="tg-lqy6"   :class="order.discountPrice != '' ? 'exist' : ''" id="discountPrice">{{ order.discountPrice }} sr</td>
```

and styled it like this:

```
#originalPrice.exist{
    display: none !important;
}
#discountPrice{
    display: none !important;   
}
#discountPrice.exist{
    display: block !important;
}
```

It is working but I want to do it through methods. I want to have a price variable in the data that takes the value of the price because I will multiply it by the amount to get the total and I can't do this with that code.

Comment: Not really clear what you want to achieve. Could you specify better?
Try not mix numbers with strings. As kako-jun said in an answer is better to set `discountPrice = -1` or `discountPrice = null` to invalidate this property.
In the tag class property comparison use: `:class="order.discountPrice > -1 ? 'exist' : ''"` or `:class="order.discountPrice != null ? 'exist' : ''"`

Answer (score 2):

You could use [conditional rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html) `v-if/v-else` :

```
<td class="tg-lqy6" v-if="order.discountPrice === ''"  >{{ order.originalPrice }} sr</td>
<td class="tg-lqy6" v-else  >{{ order.discountPrice }} sr</td>
```

Comment: Wouldn't `<td>{order.discountPrice||order.originalPrice}</td>` work?

Comment: thank you very much, I added a solution I tried that will allow me to calculate the quantity you can check it tho

Comment: was my answer helpful?

Comment: I am really sorry I didn't mean to be rude and yes it is helpful but I just created a function because I'm going to use the value for other data

Answer (score 2):

Please use `v-if`.

```html
<td class="tg-lqy6" v-if="order.discountPrice !== ''" id="discountPrice">{{ order.discountPrice }} sr</td>
<td class="tg-lqy6" v-else id="originalPrice">{{ order.originalPrice }} sr</td>
```

You don't need to add anything to the CSS.

It is not good for discountPrice to be of type string or number.
The initial value of discountPrice should be `-1`.

```
<td class="tg-lqy6" v-if="order.discountPrice >= 0" id="discountPrice">{{ order.discountPrice }} sr</td>
<td class="tg-lqy6" v-else id="originalPrice">{{ order.originalPrice }} sr</td>
```

Comment: okay well edit this thank you very much, I added a solution I tried that will allow me to calculate the quantity you can check it tho

Comment: @AhmedSarhan if the answer is helpful you could upvote it no need to say thank you